# bug querying mongodb with find on _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use this simple code to query my mongodb from Node.js with the simple driver :

```
db.collection('mycollection').find({_id:ObjectID(param_via_http_query)}).toArray(function(err,documents) {
   if (documents.length==0) {
      //do something
    }
    else {
        //send back some data about the object
    }
});
```

What's bogging me is that when the object exists in the database (the else) my code is triggered...
...but when the object does not exist (the if) my node.js server is crashing...

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: Can you show the error log?

Comment: If the `else` statement works fine, and the `if` statement doesn't, it would probably be helpful to know what the code in the `if` statement actually is.

Comment: you should share with us err.message output

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help !
By catching the error I understood the problem : basically the server was crashing for parameters who was not 12-byte long...
By checking for my param length before the query, everything is fine now.

Best.